# How do I 'hardcode' a select field value when there is no join to the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have no idea if the title makes sense, or if this relates to sql or tsql as I am relatively new to sql and come from a vba background, but below is one half of what I have (I amended it, but the BI package sql reader created the basic select/from/where's.. and it appears to use where rather than join). If it helps in understanding, I use it to populate an olap cube..so there is 1 value being read and a whole lot of associated field needed too.

I've managed to learn a bit from on here (hence why I'm thinking it may be tsql), but I'm stuck with this one.

I am getting the value *dbo.gl_acct_detail.db_amt_cc - dbo.gl_acct_detail.cr_amt_cc* and this is associated to a month (form accouting_period), org_code, acc_code and mkt_segment

Mkt_segment comes from the prj_phase table, which is 'joined' to the acct_detail table by prj_code and phase_code.  The problem is that for some acct_code's there is no prj_code or Phase_code..they are null..so there can be no link to the prj_phase table and so no mkt_segment. In this situation I want to use a hardcoded/default value in place of the mkt_segment value (that can't be obtained). I tried using a Case When for mkt_segment in the select statement but this didn't work.

I can do this in a separate query (by excluding the prj_phase table, and hardcoding the value in the select statement and putting a where dbo.acct_code.phase_code is null)..but I'm wondering how I can do it in the one query.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN substring(cast(dbo.gl_acct_detail.accounting_period as CHAR), 5, 2) < '07' 
           THEN Left(dbo.gl_acct_detail.accounting_period, 6)  - 94 
           ELSE Left(dbo.gl_acct_detail.accounting_period, 6) - 6 
    end,  
    dbo.gl_acct_detail.org_code, 
    dbo.gl_acct_detail.acct_code, 
    dbo.prj_phase.mkt_segment, 
    CASE WHEN (dbo.gl_acct_detail.fiscal_per_nbr <> '12' and dbo.gl_acct_detail.acct_code = '70199') 
           THEN '0' 
           ELSE dbo.gl_acct_detail.db_amt_cc - dbo.gl_acct_detail.cr_amt_cc 
    end
FROM 
    dbo.gl_acct_detail, dbo.sys_defaults, dbo.prj_phase
WHERE 
    dbo.gl_acct_detail.fiscal_year = dbo.sys_defaults.current_fiscal_year -1
    AND dbo.gl_acct_detail.phase_code = dbo.prj_phase.phase_code
    AND dbo.gl_acct_detail.prj_code = dbo.prj_phase.prj_code
```

Any help/suggestions on what to look into will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Try with an outer join, it will use 'null' as your default value.

Comment: Interesting to know Mark, but as I mentioned the basic code is generated by the BI package through a drag/drop of tables/fields/joins...so it's not really a habit

Comment: hi @user2636610 , this is good if u can provide sample data =)

Comment: @user2636610: code may be generated, but it can be improved, don't you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  :

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN substring(cast(dbo.gl_acct_detail.accounting_period as CHAR), 5, 2) < '07' 
           THEN Left(dbo.gl_acct_detail.accounting_period, 6)  - 94 
           ELSE Left(dbo.gl_acct_detail.accounting_period, 6) - 6 
    end,  
    dbo.gl_acct_detail.org_code, 

    dbo.gl_acct_detail.acct_code
    , 
    case
    when (dbo.gl_acct_detail.phase_code is null or dbo.gl_acct_detail.prj_code is null)
                  then 'default value'
      else dbo.prj_phase.mkt_segment
      end mkt_segment, 
    CASE WHEN (dbo.gl_acct_detail.fiscal_per_nbr <> '12' and dbo.gl_acct_detail.acct_code = '70199') 
           THEN '0' 
           ELSE dbo.gl_acct_detail.db_amt_cc - dbo.gl_acct_detail.cr_amt_cc 
    end
FROM 
    dbo.gl_acct_detail
    left join 
    dbo.sys_defaults on dbo.gl_acct_detail.fiscal_year = dbo.sys_defaults.current_fiscal_year -1

    left join  
    dbo.prj_phase on dbo.gl_acct_detail.phase_code = dbo.prj_phase.phase_code
                    AND dbo.gl_acct_detail.prj_code = dbo.prj_phase.prj_code
```

Comment: he dun want to use any join keyword~

Comment: Many thanks Ravi, that got me there, not just to work out why/how!

Comment: Although I just had to change the location of the case where in the select, I needed it on the mkt_segment rather than acct_code..but all good.

Comment: @user2636610 :I checked that, it is already updated mins ago.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to update you statements to user Inner Join key words for the other tables.

For your condition you cant use a Outer Join to the dbo.prj_phase table since the joining columns are null that row wont be picked up at all.
See [MSDN LINK to Sql Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190409%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

In this case what you can do is to make a Sub Query and have that return the null values and you then fetch that data.